# How to set directory-path of http.Dir(..) relative to the current project folder

Tags: go, directory, path

#### Situation

I'm using GoLand and there is following situation:

Following directory structure given:

```
-project
--a
---website
```

An index.html is in project/a/website/ and Main.go is located in project/a/ with following code:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./website/")))
    http.ListenAndServe(":99", nil)
}
```

If i run Main.go in GoLand with project/a/ as the project folder, you can access the webpage index.html on localhost:99 as expected but if i run Main.go with project/ as the project folder the path "./website/" in `http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./website/")))` becomes wrong.

#### Question

What do I have to set as the directory path in `http.Dir(...)`  to access the webpage on localhost:99 independent of the current project folder?

Comment: Use absolute path, then you can run your project from anywhere. You might also want to consider moving the path value into some form of configuration, say after you've finished developing your project and you're ready to deploy it to your server, a hardcoded absolute value won't help you, instead a configuration, whether file based or env-var based can fix that for you.

Comment: "What do i have to set as the directory path [...] to access the webpage [...] independent of the current project folder?" An absolute path, of course (i.e. one starting with a slash).

Comment: There is no path relative to the project source, it's relative to the cwd of the binary. The project source usually doesn't even exist when you deploy the binary.

Comment: Thanks, setting an absolute path did the job.

Comment: @mkopriva would you mind to post your comment as an answer so i can mark this question as "answered"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use absolute path, then you can run your project from anywhere.

You might also want to consider moving the path value into some form of configuration, say after you've finished developing your project and you're ready to deploy it to your server, a hardcoded absolute value won't necessarily help you, instead a configuration, whether file based or env-var based can fix that for you.